# Regex to parse certain information from email text

Tags: javascript, regex, google-apps-script

I have created a google app script to search and extract text from emails based on filtering logic and put the text into a local html file. I want to extend this to take certain elements from the text in this form email and push it into a google sheet, which I can do, but I'm having trouble getting the regex right to grab the elements I need from the form email. Here's an example of the form email with the values I want to isolate with regex bolded. Any help is very much appreciated.

*SC Assigned for Oppty with **Any Company**
URL to the Oppty: https://my.salesforce.com/0062J00000rsx85 *Opportunity Overview:* Any Company / GBP 1,000.00 Opportunity Type: **New** Business Opportunity Owner: **Jane Doe** Sales Consultant(s): **Jon Doe** Lead Source: Cold Call Close Date: 9/30/2022 Stage: **1**. Initial Call Setup Next Steps: Demo scheduled*

Comment: If you can define a rule at/around which point of the text the information is, you can write a regular expression for it. For example, company name is after "with" but before "URL", Name is after "Owner:" but before "Sales", etc.

Comment: You might want to have a look into lookahead and lookbehind.

Answer (score 0):

#### Something like this:

```
/(?<=with ).*(?= URL)|(?<=Type: ).*(?= Business)|(?<=Owner: ).*(?= Sales)|(?<=Stage: ).*(?=. Initial)/g
```